# extract opcodes from binary file

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm working on a project about metamorphic engines(for my malware course).as a first step i need to extract opcodes from a given exe file and not in hex mode,i need opcodes in assembly.can anybody tell me how?

thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english ;)

Edit: 1- I know about disassembler,as i said i want opcodes in ascii version not hex.
      2- I want to use a static method not Debbuging.

Comment: What you are looking for is known as a disassembler.

Comment: I know about disassemblers and i tried to use IDAPro but it when i try to produce .asm file,it's not in assembly language,it's bunch of hex codes like "dd 706CEE77h, 0F06F4BF7h, 706F4B99h, 8B6F4B77h, 4A6392B6h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out why IDA Pro didn't work for me.it was because the executable file was packed and need to be unpacked before disassembling.

Answer (score 0):

IDAPro would normally be the right way to do that, but since it doesn't work for you perhaps you could use a debugger to get what you need?  How about OllyDbg?

Comment: thanks for your answer.since i'm working on a static detection method for metamorphic malwares i want to use a static method.OllyDbg is dynamic i think.IDAPro is good but as i said it does not give me the ascii assembly code,just the hex version of it.